# Best way to migrate a SQL CE 4.0 database to Sql Azure

Tags: sql-server-ce, azure-sql-database

I've got an older database, developed in VS2010, which I would like to move to SQL Azure.

I was hoping I could just upload the .sdf file to SQL Azure, but couldn't find a way to get that to work.

I can't seem to open the .sdf file in Management Studio 2008 (I get "Incompatible Database Version"), so the easy option of generating a script is not available.

Any quick and easy way to get this migration done?

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is using SQL Server Compact & SQLite Toolbox, it's a Visual Studio Add-in

- In Visual Studio (I'm using 2012) go to Tools > Extensions and Updates
- Search online for "SQL Server Compact & SQLite Toolbox" and
  install it.

You will have to restart Visual Studio after install.

- Open your solution containing the .sdf file
- Connect to your SQL CE database (Your SQL CE database is probably already under Data Connections)
- Select it
- Click on the (new) icon for SQL Server Compact & SQLite Toolbox
- In the SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox right click on the database you want to export
- Script Database > Script Database Schema and Data for SQL Azure
- Select all tables
- Save the script as a .sql file.

Run the script against your SQL Azure database
If the data script is more than 50MB (which might be the usual case, you can run them with sqlcmd):

sqlcmd -U user_dbo -P password -S cloudserver -d Database -i c:\dataScript.sql -o c:\azuremigration.txt

Comment: if the script is very large it is much more efficient to move it to move it to azure blob storage and then run it from "inside azure".  do you know how to do this?

Comment: You'd have to run sqlcmd (or the bcp utility) from inside azure as well. Which would mean that you would have to run a VM as well. And everything would have to run in the same data center/region, otherwise it would have no benefit. But I'm guessing here, I don't speak out of experience. In the past I have had good experiences with SQLAzureMW, but that's been repaced with DMA and I have never used the latter. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/datamigration/dma/

Answer (score 0):

Use my SQL Server Compact addin/ standalone app to generate a SQL Azure compatible script and run the script against the SQL Azure database