# .NET move database from App_Data to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I think I've figured out how to post my data to SQL Azure using DMA, but first I need to get it onto a server connection.

How do I get my database from my app data folder onto a SQL Server?

I've been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-migrating-to-sql-server-10-of-12) but doesn't really explain it:

I currently access my data through:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
```

and this is my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Linkofy-Release.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know how your C# code is accessing the database - are you using Entity Framework, System.Data.SqlClient, or some other way?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Sorry have added it now, but it is through entity framework!

Comment: Are you just trying to move the actual data? Or just trying to point your application to a different location, and you don't care about the data in the old database?

Comment: @mason I don't care about the data its just test data :) I just want to create it right so I can push it to azure and yeah point the application to a different location

Comment: You're currently using SQL Server **CE** (Compact Edition) - this has *no* server version available. You will need to first create a compatible database schema (with tables etc.) in the full SQL Server (the *server-based* version) and somehow import your data from the SQL Server CE database file `.sdf` into that server-based SQL Server database

Comment: @marc_s ahh I see thank you! can I import my schema into a full SQL database? I have seen the schema compare option but don't know how to get my database into that

Comment: SQL Azure lets you copy the connection string from the portal itself - try using that connection string. providerName would be different. Probably `SQLNCLI11` - see here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/

Comment: Are you trying to connect to existing data, or are you also trying to work out how to migrate a .sdf file SQL azure?. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181921/best-way-to-migrate-a-sql-ce-4-0-database-to-sql-azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connected my SQL Azure to my visual studio and did a destination database through publish settings worked a treat.